# Make some fields on the header of a flatfile schema optional

Tags: biztalk

I have a flat file schema that has the header and the data.
I made some data fields optional by changing the property min occurs to 0 and it worked.
I tried doing the same in the header and the header details properties but it didn't work.
What else do I have to change?

[image: schema that I have and Data fields]

[image: Header fields]

[image: Header Details fields]

Here's part of the schema. Contains the header, headerdetails and data nodes properties, the first field of each that's mandatory and the first trailling field I want optional which is the 7th

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://ABC.ao/middleware/servicos/docfinanceiro/balancete/v1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://ABC.ao/middleware/servicos/docfinanceiro/balancete/v1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="1252" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="true" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Balancete" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Balancete">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_order="postfix" />
        <b:properties>
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Balancete' and namespace-uri()='http://ABC.ao/middleware/servicos/docfinanceiro/balancete/v1']/*[local-name()='Header' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Data' and namespace-uri()='']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>

<xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Entidade" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Data" type="xs:date">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" datetime_format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_5" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field_6" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_7" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_8" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="10" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_9" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="11" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_10" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="12" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_11" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="13" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_12" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="14" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_13" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="15" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_14" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="16" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_15" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="17" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_16" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="18" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_17" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="19" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_18" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="20" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_19" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="21" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_20" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="22" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_21" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="23" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_22" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="24" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Field_23" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="25" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

<xs:element name="HeaderDetails">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="HeaderDetails_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>

<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HeaderDetails_Child7" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>

<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Data">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="infix" sequence_number="3" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="NumConta" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>

<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Especificacao" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
```

I want this file to be accepted.
[image: Desired file]
But at the moment this is the one that works
[image: File that works]

Because biztalk is looking for the semicolon delimiters, using the first file, the first rows of data (first 6) are considered as part of the header. That's why I have to add the extra semicolons as shown in the second picture.

Comment: Show (part of) the schema so we know what you're doing.

Comment: @Ruud Added the schema

Comment: So, what *exactly* do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: @Johns-305 Biztalk is still looking for the delimiters of the header's node trailling fields. What happens is that the first rows of data are considered as part of the header. I'll add 2 prints to explain better

Comment: Ah...ok...so...does the header row have a tag or other marker to specify that it is the header?

Comment: @Johns-305 The first line in the file is the header, second is the header details. The other rows are data. I believe the respective sequence number is that one that determines that. 1 for header, 2 for header details and 3 for data.

Comment: So, it's not a file Header, it's an Entity Header.  It should work easily, you might as well add the exact error by now. :)

Comment: @Johns-305 There's no error. Biztalk considers the first 6 rows of data as part of the header. I assume because he needs the semicolon delimiters to know the header and header details are over. Don't know why the same doesn't occur in the data. The only difference between the nodes is that max_occurs is set to unbounded, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: On seconds thought please post the full schema because with the limited information available I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Ruud the full schema is too big. I'll add what's pertaining the balancete and the schema properties. That should be enough. If it isn't let me know what else you need.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro Can you at least post the full Header element? Going by the sequence numbers there are seven elements between `Entidade` and `Field_7`, so at least the two fields before `Field_7` also need to be optional if you want your first file to validate.

Comment: @Ruud I added the full Header schema. I also added 2 extra pictures to help make it clearer. You are right about that. I have to make more trailling fields optional because the header has 2 extra (entidade and Data). I'll try with min occurs = 0 in those fields too

Comment: @Ruud It worked after I changed the min occurs to 0 in the field 6 and field 7 too. Find it weird that he was ignoring 6 whole lines instead of 1 just because of that though. Add it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro I think Johns-305 pretty much answered it below: you have to make sure all trailing fields from where you want to start omitting them are optional. So you can accept that answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well....what kind of flat file?  And what do you mean by 'optional'?

You generally cannot make flat file fields optional unless they are trailing fields and the first and all subsequent fields are optionable.

This is because all flat files are position sensitive.  Field "First Name" is always in position 8 and can't shift to 7 because 6 is 'optional'.

Comment: The optional fields are the trailling ones. But I want to have the header fields also optional